# UpDating .sh file to be compatible with v20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, php7

I'm trying to update this .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
function pecl_install {
    pecl install $1
    echo "extension=$2.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/$2.ini
    echo "; priority=$3" | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/$2.ini
    php5enmod $2
}

if [ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Not running as root"
    exit
fi

echo "Installing Apache and PHP"
apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-curl

echo "Installing HTTP extension"
apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php5-dev php-http php5-mcrypt php-pear
pecl_install pecl/raphf raphf 20
pecl_install pecl/propro propro 20
pecl_install pecl_http http 30

echo "Enabling Apache modules"
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod rewrite
```

And this is my edtion:

```
#!/bin/bash
function pecl_install {
        pecl install $1
        echo "extension=$2.so" | sudo tee /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/$2.ini
        echo "; priority=$3" | sudo tee -a /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/$2.ini
        php7enmod $2
}

if [ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Not running as root"
    exit
fi

echo "Installing Apache and PHP"
apt-get install apache2 php7.4 php7.4-curl

echo "Installing HTTP extension"
apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php7.4-dev php-http php7.4-mcrypt>
pecl_install pecl/raphf raphf 20
pecl_install pecl/propro propro 20
pecl_install pecl_http http 30

echo "Enabling Apache modules"
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod rewrite
```

I do good work unto the line number 18

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php7.4-dev php-http php7.4-mcrypt>
```

It shows me these lines:

```
Installing HTTP extension
./install.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./install.sh: line 18: `apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php7.4-dev php-http php7.4-mcrypt>'
```

So, Any Help here!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove `>` from end of [line 18](https://github.com/greatfire/website-mirror-by-proxy/blob/master/install/install.sh#L18) first. So it will look like shown below:

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php7.4-dev php-http php7.4-mcrypt
```

Also it should be noted that `php7.4-mcrypt` package does not exist in official Ubuntu repositories.
So correct (in packaging terms) line 18 for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will look like:

```
apt-get install libpcre3-dev libcurl3-openssl-dev php7.4-dev php-http php-pear
```